# How do I use interfaces to provide the same functionality as multiple inheritance (overlapping inheritance)?

Tags: .net, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have a base class, from which a class and a subbase class inherit, and two more classes from the subbase.

```
Public MustInherit Class Base
    Public Function F1() As Int32
        Return 1
    End Function
End Class

Public Class B1
    Inherits Base
End Class

Public MustInherit Class SubBase
    Inherits Base
    Public Function F2() As Int32
        Return 2
    End Function
End Class

Public Class S1
    Inherits SubBase
End Class

Public Class S2
    Inherits SubBase
    Public Function F3() As Int32
        Return 3
    End Function
End Class
```

Now a new function F4 needs to be added. It is very complicated: no duplicate code allowed.

It needs to be provided to B1 and S1 only. *It must not allow S2 to expose it*.

It is suggested, that interfaces could provide multiple inheritance, but how? Since Interfaces don't carry implementations, I can't see how to use an interface to implement the new function in two classes. Could you lead me into the right direction?

```
Public Function F4() As Int32
    Return 4
End Function
```

**Edit:** Redesign no problem, as long as all shown functions (and not more) are available to B1, S1 and S2 (plus the new function F4 to B1 and S1, but not S2).

Comment: If you add: `Public Interface IFunction4 Function F4() As Int32 End Interface` and make B1 and S1 `Implements IFunction4`, S2 won't implement the interface so it won't create the method. Isn't just that?

Comment: @Jimi, but an interface has no implementation. Both B1 and S1 would require me to actually provide an implementation. Twice: both in B1 as well as in S1. In the example it's just `Return 4`, but it's a complex story in reality. Code duplication is just a no go.

Comment: I don't think you can do that unless S1 loses F2 or B1 gains F2

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to create an interface mandating to implement F4.

```
Public Interface I4
    Function F4() As Int32
End Interface
```

Then a new class implements that interface.

```
Public Class S3
    Implements I4
    Public Function F4() As Int32 Implements I4.F4
        Return 4
    End Function
End Class
```

Then the 2 classes needing F4 (B1 and S1) implement I4, and in the function's body instantiate an object of the new class S3. Since S2 does not need F4, it is not modified.

```
Public Class B1
    Inherits Base
    Implements I4
    Public Function F4() As Int32 Implements I4.F4
        Dim o3 As New S3
        Return o3.F4
    End Function
End Class

Public Class S1
    Inherits SubBase
    Implements I4

    Public Function F4() As Int32 Implements I4.F4
        Dim o3 As New S3
        Return o3.F4
    End Function
End Class
```

Pretty and elegant? Not really. Works as intended? Yes.

```
Public Class TestMI
    Public Sub MI()
        Dim b1 As New B1
        Console.WriteLine(b1.F1.ToString)   'From Class Base.
        Console.WriteLine(b1.F4.ToString)   'New F4 from S3 implementing I4.
        Dim s1 As New S1
        Console.WriteLine(s1.F1.ToString)   'From Class Base.
        Console.WriteLine(s1.F2.ToString)   'From Class SubBase.
        Console.WriteLine(s1.F4.ToString)   'New F4 from S3 implementing I4.
        Dim s2 As New S2
        Console.WriteLine(s2.F1.ToString)   'From Class Base.
        Console.WriteLine(s2.F2.ToString)   'From Class SubBase.
        Console.WriteLine(s2.F3.ToString)   'Native to S2.
        '                                    No exposure of F4, as intended.
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'd much prefer multiple inheritance, though.